# Using Grid.Mvc, css styles and scripts not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I´ve seen this question before but none of those answers work for me.
Instead of adding the lines:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

I used this in BundleConfig.cs file

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/gridmvc").Include("~/Scripts/gridmvc*"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css", "~/Content/bootstrap*", "~/Content/gridmvc.css"));
```

This is _Layout.cshtml head

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/gridmvc")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
```

And of course i´ve added @using GridMvc.Html
to the View file
I get the grid but with no styles applied to it (just built-in MVC styles) and filtering does not work, so i guess scripts ar not working neither.  Ordering and paging works
This is what i get http://i61.tinypic.com/33z62a1.png

Comment: I´ve added this line at the beggining of RegisterBundles():

    bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

now, css styles are applied but .js still don´t work.  For example, **filtering icons don´t even appear**

Comment: Seems that filtering and sorting can´t work together. Each one works fine separately